# programatically accessing Django models from another app

Tags: django, django-models

I have a moderately complicated Django project with a variety of different apps (`app1`, `app2` etc), each with their own models. I am building a `MetaApp` app to track info about each app, with a `MetaApp` class in models.py, and fields such as `appname` and `modelname`

`MetaApp` drives an index view that summarizes various aspects of each project. I would like to include a count of the database records for each app. This means that I need to programmatically access models from other apps. ***If I I know the `appname` and `modelname`, how do I programmatically access these models?***

```
projects = MetaApp.objects.all()
projects[0].appname[0].modelname.ojects.all()
```

This code results in an attribute error, because I am storing the `appname` and `modelname` as unicode strings.  What is the workaround?

Comment: which version of django are you using ?

Comment: Note that this functionality is already built into Django, in [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, this seems to be exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `django.db.models.loading.get_model()` function:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

model = get_model(app_name, model_name)
object_list = model.objects.all()
```